# Selectively downloading files with wget and regex fails on /i

Tags: regex, wget

I try to get specific files with wget and a regular expression.

The files are infographics.jpg and informatics.jpg

Here the command line:

```
wget -r -nd -P test -A jpg --accept-regex '.*\/i.*.jpg'
```

It downloads every jpg it can find instead of just the two files beginning with an "i".

If I add an "n" after the "i"...

```
wget -r -nd -P test -A jpg --accept-regex '.*\/in.*.jpg'
```

... that works perfectly, downloading the two files beginning with "in".

But not otherwise. I found that "/i" means case-insensitive. So I tried different ways to make sure the "i" is taken as a letter, not a switch, like "[i]", ... No luck.

Is this a /i problem? And may I get rid of that?

Comment: It can be for greediness. Change first regex to `/i[^/]*\.jpg$`

Comment: It worked, thanks! Just to make sure I have a correct understanding of the solution, does `[^/]*\.` mean any number of characters that are not a slash, followed by a point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More probably it's for greediness of regex. Yours matches from beginning up to an `i` (that might exist on a path, not within filename) then up to a `.jpg` sequence of characters - could not be at the end. So you need to restrict regex a bit:

```
/i[^/]*\.jpg$
```

This matches a `/` immediately followed by an `i` then without jumping over different parts of URL (`[^/]*`, filename only) ends to `.jpg` that meets end of URL as well.